# Openshift NuGet Error Dot Net Core 2.0

Tags: c#, .net-core, nuget, openshift

I have a big problem with Openshift.

First of all I wanted to create a Dot Net Core 2.0 solution. So I create a new project with API and Core 2.0.

Then I upload the solution to the repository on GitLab.

**We have a VPN connection to our network that is private.**

Everything works well until the MSBuild start and here is the log

Using SDK: 2.0.3

280 ---> Copying application source ...

281 ---> Restoring application dependencies...

282 Restoring packages for /opt/app-root/src/fassi_studio_v2/fassi_studio_v2.csproj...

283 Restoring packages for /opt/app-root/src/fassi_studio_v2/fassi_studio_v2.csproj...

> 284
>   /opt/rh/rh-dotnet20/root/usr/lib64/dotnet/sdk/2.0.3/NuGet.targets(102,5):
>   error : Unable to load the service index for source
>   https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json .
>   [/opt/app-root/src/fassi_studio_v2/fassi_studio_v2.csproj]

285 /opt/rh/rh-dotnet20/root/usr/lib64/dotnet/sdk/2.0.3/NuGet.targets(102,5): error :   An error occurred while sending the request. [/opt/app-root/src/fassi_studio_v2/fassi_studio_v2.csproj]

286 /opt/rh/rh-dotnet20/root/usr/lib64/dotnet/sdk/2.0.3/NuGet.targets(102,5): error :   Failure when receiving data from the peer [/opt/app-root/src/fassi_studio_v2/fassi_studio_v2.csproj]

287 error: build error: non-zero (13) exit code from registry.access.redhat.com/dotnet/dotnet-20-rhel7@sha256:81ec2cf307a686d5fc7bd79ebc82d831b05c45602368bc477f20506ef6c9c0fc

And now the problem:

Doesn't matter if I include NuGet.Config and change the source.
Doesn't matter if I override the enviroment variable DOTNET_RESTORE_RESOURCES
The build is always using : https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json 
And, I guess because of our interne proxy the connection is refused.

Have someone a remote idea of how to solve this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Looks like your network blocks nuget.org.
`Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json`
In some companies there is a private nuget server, maybe you forgot to use this one in the nuget settings?

Comment: Can you create an issue at https://github.com/redhat-developer/s2i-dotnetcore/issues? We'll help you debug this.

Comment: Thanks for the idea SimonsOn. We already try to change to our corporate Nuget Server. But we are having now other problems with the enviroment variable.

Comment: Thanks Tom! I will do it!